# How to forcefully logout or delete token from localstorage after a refresh in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, local-storage, token

I have created a react app and I want that each time if user refresh the browser or change the endpoint manually, then I want to delete the token(or logout) that is stored in the `localstorage` for auth purpose. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this in your App.tsx or other component that is rendered at every reload:

```
useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.clear()
},[])
```

Or add this to delete a spesific key.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.removeItem('yourKey');
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the effect hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", deleteToken);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", deleteToken);
    };
  }, []);
```